# Retrieving data from firebase in Angular based on a value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have some data in firebase ( email id and password being the keys). I'm passing an email id, and want to retrieve the corresponding password to check for validation. But, when I try to print the retrieved value on console, it prints "null" even though the data exists in firebase.

```js
getPassword(email:string)
  {
    console.log(email);
    this.db.database.ref('/facility').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value', (snapshot) => {
      //console.log(snapshot.val());
      if(snapshot.val())
     { this.userpassword = snapshot.val().password;
      return this.userpassword;}
    })
   
  
  }
```

[image: This is the database structure]

I have tried passing email as akhilesh@snu.edu.in expecting to recieve "akhilesh" from the database but received null.

```js
 verifyuser(email: string){
  
    
    this.userService.getPassword(email);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because, through `snapshot.val()`, you receive the "full" object, i.e.

```
{ Akhilesh : {
    email: .....,
    password: .....
  }
}
```

as you may have seen with `console.log(snapshot.val());`. As a matter of fact, you call the `once()` method on `database.ref('/facility')`.

---

The following will therefore do the trick:

```
var dataObj = snapshot.val();
var password = dataObj[Object.keys(dataObj)[0]].password;
```

---

Note that this solution will work if you are sure that **there is only one node corresponding to the email**.

If it is not the case you will need to loop over the snapshot, as follows:

```
this.db.database.ref('/facility').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email).once('value', snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
    var childData = childSnapshot.val();
    var password = childData.password;
  });
});
```

---

#### Answer to your comment below:

You have to wait that the Promises returned by the [`once()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html#once) method resolves, with `then()`, as follows:

```
return this.db.database.ref('/facility').orderByChild('email').equalTo(email)
  .once('value')
  .then(dataSnapshot => {
    if(snapshot.val()) {
       var dataObj = snapshot.val();
       var password = dataObj[Object.keys(dataObj)[0]].password;
       return password;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! this worked for me
But I still have an issue....when I printed the password on console , I got the right output....but when I returned the password to the login.ts script and print on console, the return type is "undefined"..how to pass the value to the login.ts script?

Comment: This still returns undefined on returning to the login.ts script

Comment: This is how I am calling the value into login.ts --
console.log(this.verifyuser(instForm.value['facilityId']));

Comment: Well, `this.verifyuser()` does not appear in your initial question... It will be difficult for me to help you with only this info. You might add your entire code to your question (do not remove the current content, just append to it)

Comment: The `getPassword()` function is asynchronous, since it returns the promises chain returned by a set of asynchronous functions. So you should also use `then()` when you call it. `getPassword().then(result => { console.log(result)})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202243/discussion-between-akhilesh-pothuri-and-renaud-tarnec).

Comment: In here, What is the output type. I retrieve like this,

__zone_symbol__state: true
__zone_symbol__value:
angle: 10
coordinates: {lat: 7.0385664, lng: 79.9080448}
userName: "Hemantha"
__proto__: Object
Symbol(Symbol.species): (...)
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): (...)
__proto__: Object